# Determine possible thermistor value in multimeter

Tags: identification, multimeter, thermistor

I have a Toptronic T835 multimeter that has a cracked component that looks like a thermistor. It is marked TR1 on the PCB. The only text on the component is first row [obscured character]B and second row [obscured character]Mz.

I have been unable to find a schematic for the multimeter and cannot measure it, because it is cracked through. Can anybody possibly assist in identifying the component and its value?

[image: PCB photo 1]

[image: PCB photo 2]

Comment: Is it possible that the silk-screened TR1 refers to the nearby transformer?

Comment: @jonk No it is that component. The silkscreen is just not visible from that angle.